# Java EE7 Standard with Hazelcast support possible?

Tags: hazelcast, java-ee-7

Running Java EE 7 Web- and Enterprise applications, I mainly use the facade pattern with an abstract facade, which is extended to lots of EJBs. I am also using the standard JPA provider EclipseLink.
Thinking about caching and clustering with Hazelcast, I would like to implement Hazelcast queries only in the abstract facade. This means a few changes to one class only and have all the queries in an in-memory Hazelcast cluster available with all the performance gains. Is this possible? Then, how do I rewrite, e.g. this method?

```
@Override
public List<T> findAll() {
CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would enable 2nd Level Cache but Hazelcast only supports Hibernate as 2nd Level Cache Provider. No support is available for EclipseLink right now.